# how to move an object a fixed distance with 1 press

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is a very simple question but after trying several time in google i am still not able to fix this.

i have a hero which walk left and right if user hold down the button and change position 5 per frame.

Now what i want is if i press a key single time (not holding) then it will go/walk normally to a fix distance( lets say `x +=50` ) and stop there.

here is my code

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;


var dPressed:Boolean = false;
var aPressed:Boolean = false;


stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , keyDownHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , KeyUpHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , gameLoop);

function keyDownHandaler(Devent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
        if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
            {
                dPressed = true;
            }
        else if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
            {
                aPressed = true;
            }
}


function KeyUpHandaler (Uevent:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if (Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            dPressed = false;
            hero.gotoAndStop("hero Stand");
        }
    else if(Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
            aPressed = false;
            hero.gotoAndStop("hero Stand");
    }   

}

function gameLoop(Levent:Event):void
{
    if (dPressed)
        {
            hero.x += 5;
            hero.gotoAndStop("hero Move Right");
        }
    else if(aPressed)
        {
            hero.x -= 5;
            hero.gotoAndStop("heroMove Left");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set up another property:

```
var counter: uint = 0;
```

Put a counter in your gameLoop function like this:

```
if (dPressed == true) {
     counter++;
     hero.x += 5;
     hero.goToAndStop("hero Move Right");
     if (counter >= 10){
         dPressed = false;
         counter = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that actually in my previous question i didn't get any correct ans . So thanks for answering, i use this code but my hero is not stop moving means somehow dPressed = false; not working , any idea ?

Comment: And i have used another button (S) for that.

Comment: sorry about this (again) actually its work i messed up somehow but its fine now thanks a lot